# Is there a repository of fan-made adventures for Numenera?

Tags: game-recommendation, published-adventures, online-resources, numenera

I am looking to start a new RPG group with my friends. We haven't chosen an RPG yet, but I am interested in Numenera. I was hoping to find an RPG that had a repository of fan-made adventures I could browse and use for the first few games, but I haven't been able to find anything like that for Numenera.

Does one exist? If not, am I missing something? I assumed all RPGs would have a site or forum where you could submit adventures for others to use.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not aware of any dedicated sites for Numenera adventures. Lots of stuff for foci, descriptors, etc but very little in terms of curated fan-made adventure content.

During a NaNoWriMo a while back, I wrote some themed adventures and posted them publicly over at http://albumadventures.com but no, no real resources that collect and curate these things to my knowledge.